Returning a linked list from a function causes an error: "member access within misaligned address" occuring on a non-existing line
I'm doing a problem in Leetcode where I have to add two numbers from a linked list, and then return a linked list from addTwoNumbers
Details of error section
Here is my full code:
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
int findOOM(int num);

struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
    int valueL1 = 0, valueL2 = 0, valueTotal;
    
    struct ListNode* temp = l1;
    int loopNo = 0;
    do {
        valueL1 += (temp->val) * (10^loopNo);
        temp = temp->next;
        loopNo++;
    } while (temp != NULL);

    temp = l2;
    loopNo = 0;
    do {
        valueL2 += (temp->val) * (10^loopNo);
        temp = temp->next;
        loopNo++;
    } while (temp != NULL);

    valueTotal = valueL1 + valueL2;
    int order = findOOM(valueTotal);

    struct ListNode* result = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    temp = result;
    int valTemp;
    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
        valTemp = valueTotal - ((valueTotal /= 10) * 10);
        temp->val = valTemp;
        if (i != order) {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int findOOM(int num) {
    int OOM = 0;
    while(num > 0) {
        OOM++;
        num /= 10;
    }

    return OOM;
}

and the error message says:
Line 70: Char 15: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [ListNode.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here

My code only goes up to line 56, however the error messages mentions an error in line 70.
The code, as seen from the screenshot, doesn't compile
I've tried returning the function with the provided linked lists as inputs (i.e. l1 and l2), and the code compiles (although the answer is incorrect, needless to say).
Perhaps does anyone have any idea on what I did wrong? Is it the way I defined my 'result' answer incorrectly?

May or may not be related, but 10^loopNo is not exponentiation in C, it's xor.  There's no built-in operator for integer powers, so you have to do it by hand with repeated multiplication.  (pow is for floating point and not suitable for integers.)

Rather than relying on cryptic error messages from online compilers, try running a compiler and debugger on your local computer.  Tools like valgrind will give you much more usable diagnostics.

Also, to get good help on this site, you should include a [mcve] which is compilable and runnable as-is.  The snippet you posted doesn't have type definitions, headers, main function, etc; someone wanting to test it would have to add all these things, and will probably just not bother and move on to someone else's post.

As a really wild guess: it may be that somewhere you have a next pointer that isn't initialized, or you didn't set the last node to point to NULL.  Since you have not given us the part of your code that initializes lists, or how addTwoNumbers is called, there is no way for me to know for sure.  Another reason for a [mcve]; people often try to post only the part of the code that they think is "relevant", but very often they guess wrong, and the bug is in some part of the code that they didn't include.  This just wastes everyone's time.

@NateEldredge perhaps I don't have a main function since this is a problem from Leetcode, and I'd assume it's called for the test cases provided by the problem? Here's the link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/

I don't use Leetcode, but if I did, I would have my own main() and some additional test cases so I could check it locally.


Your algorithm has several issues.
We do not have to use the pow(), and ^ is reserved for bitwise XOR in C.
Your algorithm to calculate the valueL1 and valueL2 can cause overflow for large numbers.
The loop for creating the resulted linked list is incorrect.


Algorithm

We create a sentinel node and a current node pointer equal to sentinel node. This is to create the linked list for final result so that we have access to the head of the linked list.

We assign the carry to zero and check while the list1 or list2 are not NULL or we have a non-zero carry:

We set the current sum to carry. If list1 is not NULL, we add its current node value to sum and move the pointer to the next node. We do the same for list2.
The new carry is sum / 10.
We create a node pointer (p). We set the value to sum % 10 and next node to NULL.
At the end, we set the current node to p.



Code
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode {
  int val;
  struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
  struct ListNode sentinel;
  struct ListNode *curr = &sentinel;
  sentinel.next = NULL;

  int carry = 0;
  while (l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL || carry != 0) {
    int sum = carry;
    if (l1 != NULL) {
      sum += l1->val;
      l1 = l1->next;
    }
    if (l2 != NULL) {
      sum += l2->val;
      l2 = l2->next;
    }
    carry = sum / 10;
    struct ListNode *p = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    p->val = sum % 10;
    p->next = NULL;
    curr->next = p;
    curr = p;
  }

  return sentinel.next;
}

struct ListNode *p(int val) {
  struct ListNode *node = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
  node->val = val;
  node->next = NULL;
  return node;
}

void print_linked_list(struct ListNode *head) {
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%d -> ", head->val);
    head = head->next;
  }
  printf("NULL\n");
}

int main() {

  struct ListNode *l1 = p(2);
  l1->next = p(4);
  l1->next->next = p(3);

  struct ListNode *l2 = p(5);
  l2->next = p(6);
  l2->next->next = p(4);

  struct ListNode *res = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);

  print_linked_list(res);

  return 0;
}


Prints
7 -> 0 -> 8 -> NULL


